# How to get the timestamp of individual records from mysql databse php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Currently working with database and my client was confused with the db.

I have a table with three columns named

```
'fname' | 'lname' | 'email'
```

- now i have inserted 50 records on 8 april
- i have inserted 30 records and updated 10 record of 8 april on 9 april
- i have inserted 20 records on 10 april

Now i want to fetch the records that were inserted or updated on particular date.

for example: i need a query such that i can fetch the records i play with on 9 april.(i.e. 30 inserted records and 10 updated records.). So i can fetch the 40 rows.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: you don't have date field in table and still expect to get values through date? what will it compare to?

Comment: You need to have created and updated timestamps for this. Which are currently not available in your table.

Comment: i am using mysql.and i think if there is a way to find the timestamp from transaction log for every record.In a transaction log, database engine automatically insert the timestamp for every records.
I came to know about this from one of the developers.
But i did not get how to find from transaction log..
Is there a way?

Comment: so we should get the details from transaction log.
but how?
plz help...
if any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to do. You need two more columns with a datetime type to store the created date and the updated date

Comment: thaank you..
@Plamen
You are right.
But issue is i already have records given by client.So it does not mean adding those date field right now...
Is it possible to get from transaction log of mysql...?

Comment: The only thing possible that I see is if you have the binlog enabled and check trough it to see when were these added

Comment: thank you @Plamen for your kind reply..
can you tell help me out to get data as per requirement if binlog is enable...?
i will check out if binlog is enable or not...

Comment: ya. binlog is ON..
i run this query:`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin'` and it return log_bin ON.
Now how i will use BINLOG..?
please help @Plamen

Comment: Check the mysqlbinlog command. It is really easy to use. You will turn the binlog to text file. You can grep for INSERT INTO $table... There in the auto generated comments you should see the time.

Comment: oh great.Thank you for kind support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add columns like **create_dt** in your table which will store the **current date** when a new row is inserted into the table

Comment: Thank you for your support...ya dats i know..
But currently i have 4 lakhs records and client needs the records of last 3 days.
so adding now create_dt column does not mean anything...
m i right?

Comment: Then you cannot get the information you want. For future, you can use what I have suggested

Comment: is there a way to get the records from transation_log of db_engine?
does db_engine automatically insert the timestamp for every records?